# Calling Clojure higher-order functions

Tags: clojure, higher-order-functions

If I define a function that returns a function like this:

```
(defn add-n
  [n]
  (fn [x] (+ x n)))
```

I can then assign the result to a symbol:

```
(def add-1 (add-n 1))
```

and call it:

```
(add-1 41)
;=> 42
```

How do I call the result of `(add-n 1)` without assigning it to a new symbol? The following produces this output:

```
(println (add-n 1))
#<user$add_n$fn__33 user$add_n$fn__33@e9ac0f5>
nil
```

The `#<user$add_n$fn__33 user$add_n$fn__33@e9ac0f5>` is an internal reference to the generated function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easy:

```
(println ((add-n 1) 41))
```

The output you saw is a function definition. Putting it between round brackets and adding a parameter is enough to call it.